# How to query to get n level depth nodes in neo4j

Tags: node.js, neo4j, neo4j-driver

I want to write a query that will fetch the ciphers(nodes) along with its child nodes to the n-level.

[image]

e.g.
if any child is having 1 child node and that child node is also having a sub child and that sub child node is also having a sub child node and it continues to the n times. then I want to fetch a result like

```
{
P: {
    // parent node info,
    child: [
        // data
        {
            a1: {
                // data
                child: [
                    {
                        a2: {
                            // data

                            // And so on...
                        }
                    }
                ]
            }
        },

        {
            b1: {
                // data
                child: [
                    {
                        b2: {
                            // data
                            // And so on...
                        }
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Try https://neo4j.com/labs/apoc/4.3/overview/apoc.convert/apoc.convert.toTree/

Comment: just add `*..` in relationship, i.e. `[:ACTED_IN*..]` in above doc. it should give desired result.
follow up question: Is it working for big db?

Answer (score 1):

```
MATCH(P)-[:child*n]->(C)
RETURN P,C
```

Will return all the nodes in the 'child' path from node P.
'n' specifies the number of hops between P and C with the child relationship.

```
MATCH(P)-[:child*]->(C)
RETURN P,C
```

Will return all the nodes in the 'child' path, irrespective of the number of child relationship hops in-between.
Reference - [Specifying varying length paths](https://neo4j.com/graphacademy/training-intro-40/05-working-with-patterns-in-queries/#_specifying_varying_length_paths)